# OpenMP causes internal compiler error

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, openmp

I wrote a little program to test the performance gain of OpenMP.
I compile using Microsoft Visual Studio.

```
void findAllPrimesUntilX() {
    for (int i = 2; i <= upToXthPrimes; i++) {
        if (i % 500 == 0) std::cout << "First " << i * 500 << "primes have been checked\n";
        if (checkPrime(i)) primes.push_back(i);
    }
    std::cout << "All primes have been calculated!\n";
}
```

this is the function calling "checkPrime(i)" which looks like this:

```
bool checkPrime(int n) {
    if (n == 2) return true;
    if (n < 2 || n % 2 == 0) return false;      
#pragma omp parallel for
        for (int i = 3; i <= static_cast<int>(sqrt(n)); i += 2) {
            if (n % i == 0) return false;
        }
        return true;        
}
```

I am now getting a "C1001 Error : An internal error has occured in the compiler."

Removing the #pragma omp parallel for solves this problem. So what's the deal?

Thanks in advance

Folling

Comment: The OpenMP specification forbids the threads to have any other exit code paths than the one via the end of the parallel region. In other words, `return` statements or `goto` to labels outside the parallel region are not allowed. The compiler should issue an error, but Microsoft's OpenMP implementation is **very** old and unsupported and apparently very broken.

Comment: Do the work sharing on the outer loop rather than the inner loop. Be careful `std::vector` though. Either reserve a chunk of memory ahead of time that will contain all the primes or fill private `std::vector` for each thread and then join them afterwards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenMP is designed to spawn numerous threads which can perform multiple independent operations simultaneously. In your case, I believe the error is caused by the fact that many threads are spawned, but only some of them are prematurely terminated by the `return false;` statement. Instead of immediately returning `false`, try setting a boolean variable:

```
bool checkPrime(int n) {
    if (n == 2) return true;
    if (n < 2 || n % 2 == 0) return false;
    bool prime = true;

    #pragma omp parallel for
    for (int i = 3; i <= static_cast<int>(sqrt(n)); i += 2) {
        if (n % i == 0) prime = false;
    }

    return prime;        
}
```

Additionally, note that using OpenMP requires that you compile with additional flags. You're probably already doing this correctly if you ran into a compiler error.